# Create calculated column based on aggregated column in pivot table

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerpivot

Presume I have the following data:

| Country | Type | Entity | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country1 | Type1 | Entity1 | 1 |
| Country2 | Type2 | Entity1 | 2 |
| Country3 | Type3 | Entity1 | 3 |
| Country4 | Type4 | Entity2 | 4 |
| Country5 | Type5 | Entity3 | 5 |

I need to override the `Entity` column where the aggregation of `Score` is greater than a threshold. The aggregation context will be provided in a pivot table.

I am not sure how, or even if, this is possible. I have tried adding a calculated column in the Power Pivot editor using `CALCULATE` and `SUMX`, but this does help with filter context from the output pivot table. I have also tried adding a measure, but you are not able to return a string in this (aggregation).

Desired pivot table output (example where threshold >= 5):

| Row Labels | Sum of Score |
| --- | --- |
| Entity1 | 6 |
| Entity3 | 5 |
| Other | 4 |
| Grand Total | 15 |

Comment: Your data and output are inconsistent. No 'Entity5' in Entity Column.

Comment: @OzanSen apologies, now updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Powerquery you will get the following result

[image]

with this M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    chType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Entity", type text}, {"Score", Int64.Type}}),
    grpRows = Table.Group(chType, {"Entity"}, {{"Sum Score", each List.Sum([Score]), type nullable number}}),
    fltRows_GE5 = Table.SelectRows(grpRows, each [Sum Score] >= 5),
    tbl = Table.InsertRows(fltRows_GE5,Table.RowCount(fltRows_GE5),{[Entity = "Others", Sum Score = List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(grpRows, each [Sum Score] < 5)[Sum Score])]}),
    result = Table.InsertRows(tbl,Table.RowCount(tbl) , {[Entity = "Total",Sum Score = List.Sum(tbl[Sum Score])]})
in
    result
```

Comment: upvote for understanding the question, and also solving it

Comment: Thanks, will this keep filter context if I apply country, for example, to my pivot table?

Comment: My solution approach uses Powerquery. If you want to filter you have to do that beforehand or in the M-Code before `grpRows`. Of course, you can automate that by using a field in the excel table itself. This can also be done for the threshold value

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve such a result with a dax table function, try this:

```
Table_Function =
UNION (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, [Entity] ),
            "Sum of Score", CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Score] ) )
        ),
        [Sum of Score] >= 5
    ),
    ROW (
        "Header", "Other",
        "Total",
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( YourTable[Score] ),
                FILTER (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, [Entity] ),
                        "Sum of Score", CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Score] ) )
                    ),
                    [Sum of Score] < 5
                )
            )
    ),
    ROW ( "Header", "Grand Total", "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Score] ) ) )
)
```

If we test the code:

[image: KDKFKFKKSDKFSK]